# Calculate length of a trace that has a fork in it?

Tags: signal, measurement, bus, trace

If a trace has a fork in it where it goes in both directions how do you measure the length? Do you count the lengths of both ends of the fork?

Asking because I am considering using a switch IC to shorten the length of a signal I am sending to multiple ports. I only ever need access to one port at I time so I figured it wouldn't harm anything.

Comment: Why do you need to know the length? Can you tell us more about the type of signal?

Comment: Why does it have a fork in the first place? That sounds like bad layout.

Comment: There are several reasons you might need to know the length of a track, and most of those require the track not to have a fork in it. Why do you think you need to know the length?

Answer (score 0):

In case that  you assumed that shorter length is better for signal.
The length of signal only measure how far signal go. if you got fork you and use 1 end at a time. you can assume that left-end have very high impedance and can be ignored.